# Firebase Firestore how to list authorized documents?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a list of documents. Let's say I have this kind of structure:

```
cards
  cardId1
    authorizedUser = someuserid1
  cardId1b
    authorizedUser = someuserid1
 cardId2
    authorizedUser = someuserid2
```

I want to list the first 2 documents for "someuserid1" and the last one for "someuserid2". What's the best way to do it ? I tried using security rules but it didn't work :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cards/{cardid} {
      allow read, write: if resource.data.authorizedUser == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

And this my Kotlin code:

```
val query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection("cards")
                    .limit(50)
val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Card>()
                .setQuery(query,Card::class.java)
                .build()

adapter = CardFireAdapter(options)
```

Any idea on what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security rules define what type of query is **allowed**.

The actual filtering still must be done in your query:

```
val query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("cards")
                .whereField("authorizedUser", isEqualTo: "someuserid1")
                .limit(50)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I used the .whereEqualTo() method since there's no .where() method (anymore?).

Comment: That was indeed a mistake in my part, the syntax is slightly different between platforms. I updated the answer.

Comment: That still means that a user obtaining an id token could list via the REST api ALL the cards, even if they have actual access to none of them.

Comment: No it doesn't. The security rules ensure that you can only query for data you're authorized to. Since the security rules are enforced on the server, and can only be modified by an administrator of the Firebase project, this is a pretty solid security scheme.